# python magic can't identify unicode filename

Tags: python, unicode

In my small project I had to identify the type of files in the directory. So I went with `python-magic` module and did the following:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory

def getDirInput():
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    return askdirectory()
di = getDirInput()
print('Selected Directory: ' + di)
for f in os.listdir(di):
    m = magic.Magic(magic_file='magic')
    print 'Type of ' + f + '  -->  ' + m.from_file(f)
```

But It seems that `python-magic` can't take unicode filenames as it is when I pass it to the `from_file()` function.Here's a sample output:

```
Selected Directory: C:/Users/pruthvi/Desktop/vidrec/temp
Type of log.txt  -->  ASCII English text, with very long lines, with CRLF, CR line terminators
Type of TAEYEON 태연_ I (feat. Verbal Jint)_Music Video.mp4  -->  cannot open `TAEYEON \355\234\227_ I (feat. Verbal Jint)_Music Video.mp4' (No such file or directory)
Type of test.py  -->  a python script text executable
```

you can observe that `python-magic` failed to identiy the type of second file `TAEYEON...` as it had unicode characters in it. It shows `태연` characters as `\355\234\227` instead while I passed the same in both cases. How can I overcome this problem and find the type of file with Unicode characters also ? Thank you

Comment: Python 2.x or Python 3?

Comment: What happen if you encode the file name? `m.from_file(f.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()))`

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack , Python 2.x

Comment: @falsetru , IO Error stating that the file doesn't exist because the unicode characters were replaced by '??' in error apparently

Comment: How about this? `m.from_file(os.path.join(di, f))`

Comment: @falsetru, I tried that too  earlier no luck, It shows same output as I posted in question

Comment: @RolfofSaxony , I thought that was what happening in the background but how do I identify the type of file with unicode filename now?

Comment: Something has mangled the byte order of 태 - it should be `\355\227\234`. Are you sure you don't have `PYTHONIOENCODING` set in your environment or `sys.setdefaultencoding` in your script?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack nope I haven't set them in my script , `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns `ascii` though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But It seems that python-magic can't take unicode filenames

Correct. In fact most cross-platform software on Windows can't handle non-ASCII characters in filenames.

This is because the C standard library uses byte strings for all filenames but Windows uses Unicode strings (technically, UTF-16 code unit strings, but the difference isn't important here). When software using the C standard library opens a file by byte-based string, the MS C runtime converts that to a Unicode string automatically, using an encoding (the confusingly-named ‘ANSI’ code page) that depends on the locale of the Windows installation. Your ANSI code page is probably 1252, which can't encode Korean characters, so it's impossible to use that filename. The ANSI code page is unfortunately never anything sensible like UTF-8, so it can never include all possible Unicode characters.

Python is special in that it has extra support for Windows Unicode filenames which bypasses the C standard library and calls the underlying Win32 APIs directly for Unicode filenames. So you can pass a unicode string using eg `open()` and it will work for all filenames.

However `python-magic`'s `from_file` call doesn't open the file from Python. Instead it passes the filename to the `libmagic` library which is written in pure C. `libmagic` doesn't have the special Windows-filename code path for Unicode so this fails.

I suggest opening the file yourself from Python and using `magic.from_buffer` instead.

Comment: Thank you , Is there anyway I can overcome this and find the type of file with unicode characters in filename?

Comment: Yes, use `m.from_buffer()` with some data (eg 1024 bytes) read from the start of the file.

Comment: wow thank you that cleared all the problems! , I'm stupid for not knowing `from_buffer()` :3

Answer (score 2):

The response from the magic module seems to show that your characters were incorrectly translated somewhere - only half the string is shown and the byte order of `태` is wrong - it should be `\355\227\234`at least.

As this is on Windows, this raises UTF-16 byte-order alarm bells.

It might be possible to work around this by encoding to UTF-16. As suggested by other commenters, you need to prefix the directory.

```
input_encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()
u_di = di.decode(input_encoding)
m = magic.Magic(magic_file='magic') # only needs to be initialised once

for f in os.listdir(u_di):
    fq_f = os.path.join(u_di, f)
    utf16_fq_f = fq_f.encode("UTF-16LE")
    print m.from_file(utf16_fq_f)
```

Comment: Thank you, I know that in python 2 not all the strings are unicode and you need to pass a unicode directory path but this doesn't solve the problem either, it creates a `IO Error` stating that file not exists as I previously commented to falsetru

Comment: Does the directory contain non-ascii chars?

Comment: Nope it doesn't , the selected directory is printed in the output in the question :)

Comment: Can you provide the full `IO Error` exception?

Comment: sorry my bad, actually it doesn't generate `IO Error` but the output stays the same as shown in above question

Comment: Please see my update. I think this might be a Windows issue. Can you try my new code?

Comment: I tried it , it throws a `TypeError: must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str` in `from_file(...)`

Comment: Which line throws that?

Comment: This one `print 'Type of ' + f + '  -->  ' + m.from_file(utf16_fq_f)`

Comment: by the way encoding all the filenames in 'UTF-16' causes errors because other filenames are not in 'UTF-16' in windows I guess

Comment: Internally, Windows uses UTF-16 for **all** filenames and the I/O API uses UTF-16. For most parts of Python, using Unicodes allows Python to talk to the API without ambiguity. I suspect there's a problem with how Python is interacting with libmagic or how libmagic is talking to the Windows I/O API

Comment: Using the code above, can you change the last line to `print m.from_file(fq_f)`

Comment: did it still the same `cannot open `C:/Users/pruthvi/Desktop/vidrec/temp\TAEYEON \355\234\227_ I (feat. Verbal Jint)_Music Video.mp4' (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Thanks for all the help, Is there any alternative to find the type other than libmagic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100879/discussion-between-alastair-mccormack-and-pruthvi-raj).